# Permutations: producing cycle notation

Tags: python, sage

Please consider the following problem: I have a certain permutation sigma:

```
sigma = [4,1,6,2,3,5]
```

the desired result is to produce the cycle notation which follows:

```
my_cycles_perm = [[4,2,1],[6,5,3]]
```

My attempt goes as per the code below, however it seems I only get as far as the first cycle but can't seem to reengage into the second one:

The idea behind the my_row_cycle function is to take a certain permutation sigma, set up a sort of circuit breaker called marker(crcuit closed when marker == 0), and iterate over the permutation until I complete a cycle, once the cycle is complete I store it into a list.

I then verify if there are still other cycles to extract from the permutation by iterating over sigma again until I find a number in sigma that isn't in the cycles extracted prior. If such a number is found I restart the process. If not I trip my circuit breaker, marker == 1 to end the entire process and output my cycle notation of the sigma permutation.

but this still seems to be utopia for me. :)

```
def my_row_cycle(sigma):
    aux_sigma = list(sigma)
    init_ref = aux_sigma.index(aux_sigma[0]) +1       #First antecedent of aux_sigma
    init_image = aux_sigma[init_ref-1]                #Image of the antecedent
    jumper_image = init_image
    row_cycle = []
    row_cycle.append(init_image)
    my_cycles_perm = []

    marker = 0

    while marker == 0:                                 #Circuit breaker
        while jumper_image != init_ref:                #establishes if cycle complete
            for x in aux_sigma:                     #iterates sigma while cycle incomplete
                jumper_ref = aux_sigma.index(x) + 1
                if jumper_ref == jumper_image:         #Condition to append to cycle
                    row_cycle.append(x)
                    jumper_image = x                   #Changing the while loop condition
        my_cycles_perm.append(row_cycle)

        for a in aux_sigma:
            for a in my_cycles_perm:
                cycle = a
                for a in cycle:                  #looking for match in aux_sigma and cycle
                    if a not in cycle:
                        row_cycle = []
                        init_image = a
                        init_ref = aux_sigma.index(init_image) + 1
                        marker = 0
                        break

                    else:
                        marker = 1

return init_ref, init_image, jumper_image, jumper_ref, row_cycle, marker, my_cycles_perm
```

after evaluation:

```
(1, 4, 1, 6, [4, 2, 1], 1, [[4, 2, 1]])
```

I can't seem to understand why my marker trips to the value "1" and yet my cycle notation is incomplete. 
I thank you in advance if you have any suggestions and or corrections.

Comment: If you want people to help you debug your code you should probably try to be as nice as possible to them by commenting your code and explaining the logic you are trying to follow.

Comment: You're right, I've been up to it for the past entire day, and posted my question at 2am while fatigued and frustrated(I know...). I've only been up to programming for a couple of days now and didn't know about the usefulness of commenting my code so despite this I've learnt something from you thanks ! Anyhow, post edited and notes taken for future questions.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this function does what you wish:

```
def to_cycles(perm):
    pi = {i+1: perm[i] for i in range(len(perm))}
    cycles = []

    while pi:
        elem0 = next(iter(pi)) # arbitrary starting element
        this_elem = pi[elem0]
        next_item = pi[this_elem]

        cycle = []
        while True:
            cycle.append(this_elem)
            del pi[this_elem]
            this_elem = next_item
            if next_item in pi:
                next_item = pi[next_item]
            else:
                break

        cycles.append(cycle)

    return cycles

print(to_cycles([]))
# []

print(to_cycles([1]))
# [[1]]

print(to_cycles([4,1,6,2,3,5]))
# [[4, 2, 1], [6, 5, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you accidentally use the variable `a` multiple times in your nested loops:

```
for a in aux_sigma :
    for a in my_cycles_perm :
        cycle = a
        for a in cycle :        # <<-- a iterates ovr cycles, so
            if a not in cycle : # <<-- a in cycle is alsways true
                # [...]
                marker = 1
            else :
                marker = 0
```

Assign seperate variable names to all distinct iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I thought these variables weren't linked, however in the function I don't seem to get any results despite that.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial reduction of BallpointBen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36692883)

```py
def to_cycles(perm):
    pi={i+1: p for i,p in enumerate(perm)}
    cycles=[]
    while pi:
        next_item=pi[next(iter(pi))]
        cycle=[] #arbitrary starting element
        while next_item in pi:
            cycle.append(next_item)
            next_item=pi[next_item]
            del(pi[cycle[-1]])
        cycles.append(cycle)
    return(cycles)
```